# Removing NA's from a scraped web string

Tags: r, rvest, stringr

I'm playing around with `rvest`

Unfortunately, I can't share the website, but a part of my script looks like this:

```
test %>% html_nodes("li") %>% html_attr(name = "data-messagescore")
```

This returns a messy output like this:

```
[1] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
 [26] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
 [51] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
 [76] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[101] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[126] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[151] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[176] NA   NA   "2"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "0"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[201] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "0"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[226] NA   "1"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "-1" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[251] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "1"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[276] NA   NA   NA   "0"  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[301] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA  
[326] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

But all I want is an output with the five numbers listed like this:

```
[1] "2"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "-1" "1"  "0"
```

I tried:

```
test %>% html_nodes("li") %>% html_attr(name = "data-messagescore") %>% na.omit()
```

It returned:

```
[1] "2" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "2"
attr(,"na.action")
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
 [32]  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62
 [63]  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93
 [94]  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124
[125] 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155
[156] 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187
[187] 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220
[218] 221 222 223 224 225 226 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253
[249] 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 280 281 282 283 284 285 286
[280] 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317
[311] 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

I can't figure out what's going on there? It starts off correct (See the first return for [1]) but then by the end it just says `[1] "omit"`

What would be the best course of action?

Comment: `na.omit`? You'll presumably want to coerce to integer, too.

Comment: @allstaire see my edit

Comment: you are just getting the positions that where remove with the na.omit

Comment: Yeah, `na.omit` adds attributes. They don't hurt anything, but can be dropped. There's not an elegant way to do so when piping, though; one option might be `na.omit() %>% \`attributes<-\`(NULL)`. You can also subset with braces if you want to pipe it, e.g. `{.[!is.na(.)]}`

Comment: Maybe a better way to address this question is to simply only select nodes that have a suitable attribute, e.g. with `html_nodes("li[data-messagescore]")`

Comment: Bingo! There we go.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work `test[!is.na(test)]`?